# How can I remove upload folder from url using opencart 2?

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to remove upload folder from opencart URL. I have tried with following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Route all request to production folder
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ upload/$1[L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?siteName.ae$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^upload/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ upload/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?siteName.ae$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ upload/ [L]
```

But when I adding this code then login does not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/upload/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /upload/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the rewrite base to /{foldername here}/